# Error -22 when inserting IPv6 blackhole route

Tags: networking, ipv6, iproute

I am trying to insert a blackhole route with the command:

```
ip -6 route add blackhole 2001:db9:9::9
```

After I execute this command and display the table, the route is there but it has an `error -22` message at the end

```
(other routes)
blackhole 2001:db9:9::9 dev lo  metric 1024  error -22
(other routes)
```

This doesn't happen in IPv4. What could be the problem here? I'm pretty sure this is the right syntax. I'm using kernel version 4.10.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error -22` is not an error that occurred when adding the route, but shows the error (`EINVAL`) that a local sender will get when trying to send a packet through the blackhole route. Nothing to worry about.